# How to remove a specified pattern from the string with python regex?

Tags: python, regex

Here is my string `'2018-01-31 05:29:37 | Jan Pong Lee | [Number of contacts]:1'`

I would like to remove `'| Jan Pong Lee |'`. The name can have 2 or 4 words, is there a way to do that?

Comment: I am still unsure about your requirements.. it is very much ambiguous. If you cant then give more input and expected output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex to match and replace it with empty string,

```
\|[^|]*\|
```

**Explanation of this regex:** This regex basically captures a `|` followed by any character (except `|`) zero or more times and finally captures a `|` character and then stops capturing and replaces all matched characters with empty string.

**[Live Demo](https://regex101.com/r/1PZXHe/1)**

Here is the python code for same,

```
import re

s = '2018-01-31 05:29:37 | Jan Pong Lee | [Number of contacts]:1'
ret = re.sub(r'\|[^|]*\|', '', s)
print (ret)
```

Which prints the remaining string after removal of `| Jan Pong Lee |`. This will work no matter whatever number of words you have inside those pipes.

```
2018-01-31 05:29:37  [Number of contacts]:1
```

Comment: Thats very helpful!! thanks! May I know what does it mean?

Comment: @DanniPeng: Glad to help :) I have added explanation of what the regex does. Hope that helps. Let me know if you have any query further.

Comment: I've read through the demo as well, it helps me solve the biggest problem of today. Thank you again!

Comment: Pleased to help. If my answer helped you, please consider marking it as accepted answer which may benefit users looking for a similar answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution:

```
old_str =  '2018-01-31 05:29:37 | Jan Pong Lee | [Number of contacts]:1'
new_str = "{} | {}".format(old_str.split('|')[0], old_str.split('|')[2])
```